# Set language to Swedish

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this in my partial view:

```
 <tr>
    <% for (int currentDay = 0; currentDay < 7; currentDay++)
       { %>
    <th>
    <%= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[currentDay] %>
    </th>
    <% } %>
</tr>
```

The weekday names render correctly in Swedish, but somehow the week starts with Sunday, while the first day of week in Sweden is Monday. How can I fix this?

And furthermore, is there some easy way to make it render first letter in weekday names as uppercase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't strange, the DayOfWeek enum is just defined as Sunday = 0. You have to do this by your own, using `DateTimeFormatInfo.FirstDayOfWeek` in `System.Globalization`.

Correct code would be:

```
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
        int substraction = (int)ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

        int dayToGet = 0; //should return monday

        var daynames = ci.DateTimeFormat.DayNames;

        string day = daynames[dayToGet + substraction >= 7
            ? (dayToGet + substraction - 7) : dayToGet+substraction];
```

Dayname to upper depends on your culture setting, so I guess in Sweden it's all lower case, you can do `str.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + str.Substring(1)`, to get the first char up.

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss understanding the purpose of DayNames.  It will always start with "Sunday" or the appropriate language equivalent for "Sunday".  Regardless of which culture is used.

Consider this code:-

```
string dayname = myCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[myCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek]
```

What would you expect FirstDayOfWeek to be in the Swedish culture?  Ans: 1
What would you expect to find in dayname? Ans: The swedish name for "Monday"
Hence you need element 1 for DayNames to be "Monday" and you'd expect the name previous to it at position 0 to be the name for "Sunday".

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
for (int currentDay = 0; currentDay < 7; currentDay++)
{
    int currentLocalizedDay = ((int)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek + currentDay) % 7;

    Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[currentLocalizedDay]);
}
```

Or changing your original code, to something like this:

```
<tr>
    <% for (int currentDay = (int)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek; currentDay < 7; currentDay = (currentDay + 1 % 7))
       { %>
    <th>
    <%= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[currentDay] %>
    </th>
    <% } %>
</tr>
```